# 'conda activate' not actually activating a virtual env

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda, anaconda3

I'm having a problem that `conda activate` would never actually activate the virtual environment and looking for a solution to fix it.
It happens like this:

```
$conda --version
conda 4.13.0
$conda info -e 
  base   *  C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3 
  py38      C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\py38 
$conda activate py38
$conda info -e  
  base   *  C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3 
  py38      C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\py38
```

I've heard that `conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs` would fix this and tried it, but it never caused any difference.
(c.f. https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626#issuecomment-313913036)

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: What terminal and shell? Some terminals, like VSCode and tmux are known to obviate Conda’s activation functionality.

Comment: It took place with both Windows PowerShell and GitBash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been self-fixed by executing `conda init powershell` and rebooting the computer.
Somehow the terminal hadn't seemed to reflect my setting properly.