# Conda activate env does not activate the environment (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, environment

The conda `activate` command does not produce an error, but does just not do anything. The requested environment is still deactivated.

Hello! I am relatively new to python and completely new to VS Code.
When trying to set everything up, I encountered several problems – that may partly be caused by my seldom usage of python (only for teaching, not in daily use).
Here I will focus on the conda environments – hoping that this will solve a couple of other problems automatically.

I created a new environment (env-python3-10) that uses python version 3.10 (because all my other environments are outdated...). When creating it, I did not add any libraries, so it contains only a couple of default ones. To add libraries (e.g. numpy), I first need to activate the environment by typing:

`conda activate env-python3-10`

But by listing the environments afterward, I see that the active environment is still base, not the one I activated. I also tried to activate (without conda), which does not cause any reaction either.
I found another thread where it was described that I maybe need to initialize conda within the shell first with:

`conda init`

This did apparently not change anything – so I assume that conda was already initialized. I also tried more explicitly (following ['conda activate' not actually activating a virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924729/conda-activate-not-actually-activating-a-virtual-env))
`conda init powershell`, which did not make any changes either.

I tried the

`source path\to\environment`

command (not shown) but this produces an error:
`The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,  function, script file, or operable program.`

I am not sure how to proceed here – probably there is an easy solution that I simply don't see. I appreciate your help very much!

The reaction to `conda activate` and `conda init`:
[image: reaction to conda activate and conda init]

Comment: Do these commands work normally when you run them from the `anaconda prompt`?

Comment: they used to work - but maybe that is already part of the problem: I am not able to open the anaconda prompt anymore.

Comment: Maybe related information to that: when I try to update python to a newer version in the base, I run into the problem that the "current user does not have permission" to make changes to the Anaconda3 directory. I know that this is not true, because I have full admin rights for my computer. But maybe I should rather figure out how to re-retrieve access. Maybe this is not related to the original question anymore then. Do you by any chance know where to start searching to find a solution for this?

Comment: That is normal. You would need to start the cmd or powershell with elevated privileges. By default it starts without admin access, even if your account has them

Comment: What happens when you start your anaconda prompt? Do you remember when these issues started, i.e. what you had done leading up to them?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks you for pointing that out!

The anaconda prompt is simply not opening any more. If I choose to open it, it opens and closes immediately. If I want to open the entire Anaconda user interface, it is stuck at the initializing symbol, which only disappears when rebooting the computer.